# Connecting GPIOs on two boards with independent power supplies

Tags: pcb, fpga, dc-dc-converter, gpio, ldo

I'm trying to design a board that will accept UART/8N1 input from another board at 3.3V.  While the two boards share a common GND (obviously), they otherwise have totally independent power supplies:  one is powered by USB VBUS which is regulated down to 3.3V, and the other by an AC adapter that is independently regulated down to 3.3V.

My question is this:  obviously the two different 3.3V rails are not going to be at exactly equal potentials.  Both have some amount of ripple, both will be experiencing load transient spikes at various times, no regulator is perfectly accurate, there are thermal de-rating effects, etc.  Therefore, when connecting the GPIO output pin from the other board to the GPIO input pin on my board, do I need a current-limiting resistor in series with the signal?  Do I need a low Vf diode to prevent current back flow out of my board through the GPIO?

Here is a diagram that I hope makes the situation clearer:

[image: diagram of the two boards with independent power supplies]

Both the output GPIO (on "Other Board") and the input GPIO (on "My Board") are based on similar Lattice ECP5 FPGAs, and the [datasheet for this FPGA family](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=50461) says that IO pins can handle voltages above or below 3.3V by an absolute maximum of about 300mV or preferably no more than 165 mV under recommended operating conditions.  Since the voltage regulators used on the two boards both respond to load step transients with a max of about +/-50mV and have ripple deviations of less than that, I'm not concerned that the two voltage rails will deviate substantially -- except in the case where one board is powered off completely and the other is up and running.

What I am mainly trying to understand is whether there can be current flow between an input GPIO pin and an output GPIO pin given that one board's 3.3V rail may actually be 3.25V while the other board's 3.3V rail may actually be 3.35V.  It would seem to me that in this case, which is going to be happening all the time, current flow would flow from the slightly higher 3.35V voltage rail to the slightly lower 3.25V rail through the GPIO line?  (I can't find anything in the datasheet that says that single-ended GPIO inputs have any particular level of impedance, and the datasheet seems to imply that any required impedance matching should be done externally.)  Assuming the connection between the two GPIO pins is very low-Z, won't this current flow be essentially infinite in magnitude until one of the chips dies?

In summary, my specific questions are:

1. Should I add a series resistor that holds the current flow to 8mA (max that the output GPIO can source and max that the input GPIO can sink)?  If so, do I pick the value based on the maximum possible voltage difference, which would be ~3.5V in the case where one of the boards is powered down and the other is still running (3.3V + maximum possible transient + safety margin).
2. What effect would adding a series resistor have on signal integrity, specifically signal rise times and slew rates?  This is a single-ended, unidirectional signaling protocol, but any real world resistor is going to have some parasitic reactance baked into it (either inductive, capacitative, or both).
3. Should I be doing anything to clamp the voltage on the GPIO interconnect line to 3.3V, e.g., with a Zener?  Would this help or hurt my quest not to fry chips?

References that are similar but failed to truly answer my question:

- (1) [Connecting SPI with two different voltage reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609134/connecting-spi-with-two-different-voltage-reference), (2) [Can a board have two power supply circuits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245911/can-a-board-have-two-power-supply-circuits), (3) [DC DC Converters in Parallel for double current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62006/dc-dc-converters-in-parallel-for-double-current)
- this [TI whitepaper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua550/slua550.pdf?ts=1698231588070) has a great discussion of power supply OR'ing with a FET controller (they recommend the TI TPS2412 and an equivalent OR'ing controller from Linear is LTC4370), but since I'm not trying to combine the two boards' 3.3V rails, ultimately that didn't seem relevant to me.

I was asked in the comments about intended bit rate for the UART.  I intend to start modestly (e.g., 9600 baud), but would like to reapply the same basic design to faster and more complex scenarios like LVDS at higher (couple hundred MHz) speeds, if I can make it work.  Thank you for the question.

Comment: Can you edit your question (don't add in comments) and specify what bit rate your UARTs are running at. It's obviously a much different situation at 300 bps than at 3 Mbps, for example. Thanks.

Comment: While important question, don't think there is much problem when boards are powered up, that's the easy case. You must be more concerned what happens when only one of the boards is powered up, will the FPGAs damage. Someone will forget to plug something in, one board will always power up before the other, PCs can go to sleep or shut down while other board is powerd, or someone may disconnect mains while a laptop will power the other board. No amount of diodes or resistors help, it must be done correctly.

Comment: if these are dev boards, very often there are jumpers and extra connectors which allow an external 3V3 or 5V to be connected. If that is the case, it might be easier to try to power both from a common supply.

Comment: @danmcb Yes, "other board" is a dev board and usually those have pin headers for other input voltages besides USB.  In this case, it isn't possible without cutting a trace (to disable their 3.3V buck converter) and then applying 3.3V to what they regard as a voltage output.  I could do this; there's no diode or anything blocking me, but it means no one else could use my board because it's unlikely they would want to permanently remove USB-sourced 3.3V.

Comment: I don't understand the question in "Edit 2". Why would an input "actually be" an output? This is starting to sound like an XY problem -- perhaps you should explain a bit more about the actual application.

Comment: I just meant that the only way I can imagine an input asserting a high voltage and sourcing current is if I, the designer, mistakenly configured it as an output.

Comment: Ah. But that's actually fairly unlikely. In FPGA development, you normally establish the type and direction of I/O pins early in the process, and never touch it after that. But you can still take extra precautions during that phase of the development that can be removed later (before you get into performance issues).

Comment: I deleted your "EDIT 2" (and removed the unnecessary "EDIT" text from the post) since your second edit is really another question. It should be asked separately as a new question if you need it answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hot socketing" is the name that Lattice uses in the ECP5 datasheet and app-notes for the capability that addresses your questions.

Using the correct I/O banks, LVDS signals, and correct configuration of the internal termination rsistance, bias, and clamps, no external components are required.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw the datasheet discussion of "hot socketing," but did not understand it was applicable to this question.  Really appreciate your reply here.

Answer (score 14):

In situations like this, I like to use an optical coupler ([example](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/isolators-solid-state-relays/detail.TLP2355.html)) in between the two systems. The systems will remain electrically isolated, so no current will flow between them in either direction.  They can have completely incompatible voltage rails, they can even have different *grounds*.  I find them particularly useful when I don't know how the device's pins behave at system startup or when one device may have power when the other doesn't.  Isolating the two systems eliminates an entire class of problems.  The downside is that these couplers are primarily one-way circuits.  Isolated bi-directional communication is a bit more complicated.

Comment: "no current will flow between them in either direction" ... The current necessary to drive the LED in the optocoupler will flow between them in both directions.

Comment: @LilyFinley: If one views the LED and transistor as each being part of one of the systems, no current will flow across the boundary between the systems.

Comment: @supercat, Sneftel: Unless the boards are linked by optical fiber (possible, but not with a self-contained optocoupler) or the optocoupler straddles the gap between boards (limits the distance between boards and is prone to mechanical failure), then the optocoupler will have to exist on exactly one of the two boards. A pair of wires must then run between the boards that carries either the LED current or the phototransistor current, depending on which side the optocoupler is on.

Comment: @LilyFinley: If a pair of devices are connected via a simple unidirectional optical link, the collection may be functionally partitioned into three parts: 1. The device which does the transmission, 2. A small assembly that contains a connector and the LED portion of an optocoupler., and 3. Everything else in the receiving device.  No current would flow between #1 and #3.  The situation is somewhat analogous to some the special customs areas in some country's ports; goods which arrive in the country via one ship, and are then loaded onto some other ship without leaving...

Comment: ...the special customs area aren't legally seen as ever having been imported or exported from the country containing the special customs area, even if they enter an area which is geographically within the country's borders.

Comment: @LilyFinley Optocouplers typically straddle the gap between boards, except it's usually done by placing an electrically-isolated "island" on one of the boards.  Board A runs a cable to a connector on board B's island, and the coupler passes that signal safely off the island and onto the rest of board B. The island is physically attached to board B, but electrically it's only part of board A.

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, as long as both boards are powered up and their power supplies are within specification for the FPGAs (e.g., ±5% or ±10%), connecting the GPIO pins directly to each other should be no problem. Inputs on a powered-up FPGA have a very high impedance, as long as the pin voltage remains within the normal operating range.

But if you want to have one board powered and the other not, then you'll have to take precautions. In particular, it's possible that the "other board" may try to drive a logic high signal into an unpowered input on "my board". This would drive current through the protection diodes on "my board" into its power supply rail, and this may have undesirable effects. (And vice-versa, of course.)

You can establish protocols to prevent this issue. For example, you could require that the GPIOs on "other board" are tristated or driven low before power is removed from "my board". But if that can't be guaranteed, then yes, some current-limiting series resistors might be called for.

Comment: One should really assume that the laptop and the AC adapter will never power up at the exact same instant, so the protocols mentioned here should always be implemented. Great answer and my +1

Answer (score 1):

You should check the datasheets for the max/min values of one FPGA's output, vs the other's acceptable input range. Generally speaking, you can connect two logic devices that are both 3v3 logic together. While there might be a 0.05V difference between the rails, the input of an FPGA is relatively high impedance, so whether your logic is 3.3V or 3.35V represents a tremendously small amount of current difference.

You could check the other data sheets, and see what values come up with. If both FPGAs are ECP5 then there's likely no problem. For instance, the maximum input for one of the 3.3V logic groups LVCMOS33 is 3.465V, the maximum output is Vlogic - 0.27V. Given that the maximum allowed value for Vlogic is 3.465V, there's no way for one FPGA to generate too high and output voltage for the other to use as an input.

Dave points out that there is a case for one FPGA not booting properly if its input pins are driven. You need to read the datasheet and check if this is a problem, which may call for a buffer or similar, or a code fix. Again the datasheet will tell you for definite whether the input needs to be tri-stated, strapped, or whatever at boot.

You could add a small series resistor to limit the current, but this would likely have no effect. A Zener again would be unlikely to do anything. This particular instance calls for a good thorough read of the datasheets.